# Should we commit manifest.json file to git repo when using rails webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, yarnpkg, webpacker

I am using webpacker for the React installation on Rails. The problem I am facing is on staging environment.

```
 Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest. Your manifest contains: { }
```

Do we need to push our local manifest.json file located at **public/packs**? I suppose it should be there as rails precompiles the assets.
Also how does webpacker creates the manifest.json file in production environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `staging.js` configuration file for webpacker?

There is a corresponding configuration file for each Rails environment you have stored within `/config/webpack`. If your Rails Environment is set to staging and you don't have a corresponding staging.js then you will run into problems.

The [webpack-manifest-plugin](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) library is responsible for generating the manifest.json file. (The setup for this is stored in `Rails.root/config/webpack/shared.js` which is shared between the different environment configuration files.

You shouldn't need to check this into your repository. (Indeed the webpacker gem even adds `/public/packs` to your .gitignore).

This is because manifest.json is a generated file.